# Chord with the smallest length

Tags: euclidean-geometry

If I have a point K inside a euclidean disc what will be chord (chord which goes through the point K) with the smallest length. I think it will be chord which is perpendicular to the diameter, which goes through the point K, but I don't know is this true. I tried to prove this with formula of length of the chord $L=2R \sin (A/2)$, where $A$ is angle between two radii drawn to the ends of chord, but the only thing I deduced from this formula is that length would be the smallest when a is the smallest. So I'm stuck with this. Is my assumption true (if so can you help with the proof) and if not what chord will have the smallest length ?

Comment: Yes, this is true, and just as important, $K$ will be the midpoint of this chord.

Comment: Draw the perpendicular from the centre $O$ to a chord through $K$. Note that the shorter the perpendicular distance the longer the chord.

Comment: @Arthur Kind of

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I said that I'm talking about chord which goes through point K.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier He said _in_ the circle, not _on_ the circle. Now that it's edited to "inside", it's even clearer.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier OP said $K$ is in the circle. And it is a fixed point.

Comment: @Arthur I see that now. Yet it doesn't make sense, you should say disc in that case.

Comment: @Arthur You beat me by 8 sec

Comment: @ArnaudMortier No, I don't think so. I would personally either use in or inside a circle, or on a disc, and those would all mean the same to me. Now, _on a circle_ means something different from these, I agree.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Inside the circle.

Comment: @Arthur a circle is $1$-dimensional, if you say *in* a circle when you mean inside the bounded component of its complement, that's not proper speaking.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier If you required that people were that precice with their language all the time, writing anything would take ages, and reading it would take longer. Abuse of terminology is a thing for a reason, and I don't think many would have actual trouble understanding what "a point inside a circle" means, which is the _entire point_ of speaking and writing in the first place: being understood. Overzealous pedantry actively hinders communication in some cases, and it is therefore something I oppose strongly.

Comment: @Arthur I'm not being pedant, I honestly pictured a point on a circle when I first read the question. On the contrary, knowing the correct words to use is precisely a way to *be understood*, nothing more. I have to admit that "inside a circle" would have been clearer though - and I would not have found it necessary to intervene.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yeah, you're right. When it said "in" it was easy to confuse it, and avoiding confusion is also a big part of communication. Sorry I ranted off on you.

Comment: @Arthur no worries. I also understand why you could think that I was just nitpicking.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier OK, sorry, you're right, I needed to be more presice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am.afraid Arthur, Winter said it all .

Just for fun:

Point $K$ given, inside a circle .

For definiteness consider the chord $KM$ , where $M$ is the centre of the circle.

$K$ divides the chord $KM$  into $2$ segments of lengths $a$ and $b.$

Inersecting Chord Theorem:

$ab = xy$ where $x,y$ are the lengths of segments formed by any chord through $K.$

$2$ equations:

1)$xy=ab=C$ (constant , given)

2)$S:= x +y $.

Want to minimize $S$ with the constraint 1).

Use 1) to eliminate $y$:

$S = x + C/x $.

AM-GM  :

$S = x+C/x \ge 2√C.$

Minimum attained for $x=C/x= √C$.

Then $y= (ab)/√C =√C$.

Hence $x=y$ , the perpendicular chord to  chord $KM
$.

Note: $KM$ is a symmetry axis, hence $x=y$ implies the chord through $K$ is perpendicular.

Comment: Wait, how can you have chord CM where M is the center of a circle ?

Comment: K any point \not= M. Join KM, diameter. Consider any chord through K . Well a special chord is  the diameter. Do I miss out here?

Comment: M is center of the circle ?

Comment: Yes M the centre of circle, also mentioned in the answer.Let me know if there is a bug.Thanks.:)

Comment: If M is center of a circle and K is point inside the circle how can KM be a chord ?

Comment: Have a look: https://www.google.de/search?q=chord+circle&oq=chord+circle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.20516j1j7&client=ms-android-motorola&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Isn't the diameter also a (special) chord? What do you say?

Comment: Yes, diameter is a chord. But if you have segment KM where K is a center of a circle and M is inside a circle, it can't be a chord because chord is a segment with endpoints which lie on a circle, but center of a circle (point M in your case) doesn't lie on a circle and point K is inside a circle so it also doesn't lie on a circle, so how can KM be chord ? Or, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I get the confusion. Draw a circle. Put in point K. KM , M centre, is a  line that intersects circle(diameter).  Let the points of intersection with circle be A and B(opposite). Now set a=KB, and b =KA.Is this better?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Sure Ok? If not say so.:)?

Comment: No, I got it. KM is a line, not a segment, and when it intersects the circle it creates a chord, am I right ?

Comment: Yes!!!!!Look at line KM, you have a line, Forget M for the moment .Line cuts the circle and from K to one end, intersection point with circle is (length) a from K, to the other intersectionn point (opposite) is (length) b. Horrible English but think you got it.:)))

Comment: Yeah, I understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a unit circle around the origin $O$. A secant $\ell$ having distance $d(\ell,O)$ to $O$ is of length $$L=2\sqrt{1-d(\ell,O)^2}.$$ We can minimize this by maximizing $d(\ell,O)$.

Now let's restrict to secants $\ell$ through $K$. We know that $d(\ell,O)$ is the length of a line segment between $O$ and $\ell$, which is perpendicular to $\ell$. The point where this segment meets $\ell$ is the closest point of $\ell$ to $O$. All other points of $\ell$ are further away from $O$. Because $\ell$ has to go through $K$, it cannot have a distance greater than $d(K,O)$ from $O$, but by choosing $K$ to be the closest point on $\ell$ to $O$, we also ensure that $d(\ell,O)$ is not smaller than $d(K,O)$. Therefore, this maximizes $d(\ell,O)=d(K,O)$ and minimizes the secants length to:

$$L_{\min}=2\sqrt{1-d(K,O)^2}.$$

Since the segment from $O$ to $K$ is a (part of the) radius of the circle, and meets $\ell$ perpendicularly in $K$, your intuition was right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош You are welcome. If you like some answer then feel free to upvote them. I say this because I notices that you not even upvoted the accepted answer. You have enought reputation to do so. Up- and downvotes are [an important part of the StackExchange model](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Oh, OK, I didn't knew that can upvote, because earlier I couldn't.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Yes, you need at least 15 reputation to do so. You reached them some time ago ;)

Answer (score 1):

Given any point $P$ and any circle $C$, the power of $P$ with respect to $C$ is defined as follows:

> Take a line through $P$ that intersects $C$ twice, at $A$ and $B$. The power of $P$ with respect to $C$ is $|PA|\cdot |PB|$, and is independent of what line was chosen.

(According to some conventions the power is *negative* when $P$ is on the inside of $C$ and positive when $P$ is outside, but we will say it is positive. Until we have to compare powers of several different points it doesn't matter.)

Given a chord through $K$, the power of $K$ with respect to the circle is length of the two parts of chord on either sides of $K$. It is the same no matter which chord you draw. You want the sum of the two parts to be minimal.

Now note that if two quantities vary so that their product is the same (such as the lengths of the two parts of the chords), their sum is the least when the quantities are equal. (Replace "their product" with "the square root of their product" and "their sum" with "their average", and you've got exactly the AM-GM inequality, which proves this statement.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer